# Sql LocalDB 2012 и sqlxml 4.0

Tags: c#, sql-server, xml, sql-server-localdb

Собственно установил отдельно этот LocalDB (не устанавливая Express 2012, просто скачал msi). Все работает. Теперь пытаюсь загрузить туда информацию из xml используя SQLXML 4.0 следующим образом:

```
SQLXMLBULKLOADLib.SQLXMLBulkLoad4 objBL = new SQLXMLBULKLOADLib.SQLXMLBulkLoad4();
objBL.ConnectionString = "Provider=sqloledb; server=(localdb)\v11.0; database=mynewdb; integrated security=SSPI";
objBL.ErrorLogFile = "error.xml";
objBL.KeepIdentity = false;
objBL.SchemaGen = true;
objBL.SGDropTables = true;
objBL.Execute("AS_NORMDOC.xsd", "AS_NORMDOC.xml");
```

Получаю такую ошибку на `Obj.Execute` :

> COMExeption не обработано
>
> Error connecting to the data source.

В просмотре сведений  HResult и ErrorCode имеют значение -2147467259

Comment: Проверьте по списку тут: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15031548/1985167

Comment: @andreycha Да на строку подключения он не ругается, обычно если дело в ней, то пишет InvalidConnectionString

Answer (score 1):

Если в строке подключения точно все правильно, то я думаю, что надо загружаемый документ посмотреть на наличие ошибок.
Вот пример на msdn: https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms171878%28v=sql.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Скопируйте файл базы данных в папку с программой (Debug/Release).

Answer (score -1):

для (localdb) попробуйте в строке подключения `Provider=sqlncli11`

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?